# how to insert username or email in email body for each recipient in gmail API

Tags: php, email, gmail-api

I want to send same email to each recipient in email but with slightly different body. Like if I have 2 recipients in email's `to` field:

```
1) abc@gmail.com

2) xyz@gmail.com
```

So for the first recipient, email body should appear something like this:

**Hi abc@gmail.com. We are glad to see you here.**

and for the other recipient, it should appear something like this.

**Hi xyz@gmail.com. We are glad to see you here.**

Requirement is to send email to both recipients at once using Gmail API. I'm able to send same email to each recipient, but I need to send slightly different email body to each recipient. Please help me out in this. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank.

Comment: "Requirement is to send email to both recipients at once using Gmail API" - do you mean with only one request to the API?

Comment: use placeholders for the individual data and then replace them

Comment: @meta yes, in one request.

Comment: @Bernhard I want to send email in one request, placeholder is useful when we need to send emails separately. If you think you can use placeholders to meet my requirements then please post a answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with the constraints you've mentioned (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#sending_messages).

For this to be possible the API would need to provide some kind of template engine, but this would be complicated and confusing.

You need to do this in two separate requests.

Not sure why you imposed this constraint on yourself, maybe if you share a reason we could find a different way to solve it.

Comment: Actually I want to track email of each recipient whether they've opened it or not. for this I am using an hidden image tag at the end of message body and calling my tracker script using `src` attribute. And I need to pass email to tracker script to know that which person opened it.

Comment: Ok, depending if it's a commercial project or just learning... If it's the former: you may want to consider different mail providers, for example https://sendgrid.com/ is doing that. Most probably mailchimp.com as well. They'll do the tracking (and more) for you, and you don't have to code it. Also - you'll need better support than google to advise you how to not get on the spammers blacklists etc.

Comment: But I need to do it via Gmail API. cant use 3rd party.

Comment: Then you need to send requests one by one.